# Changing 2D array for Codeigniter compatibility batch insert

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
[{
    "synonyms": [{
        "synonyms": "s1",
        "wordId": 117
    }, {
        "synonyms": "s2",
        "wordId": 117
    }, {
        "synonyms": "s3",
        "wordId": 117
    }, {
        "synonyms": "s4",
        "wordId": 117
    }]
}, {
    "synonyms": [{
        "synonyms": "s5",
        "wordId": 118
    }, {
        "synonyms": "s6",
        "wordId": 118
    }, {
        "synonyms": "s7",
        "wordId": 118
    }]
}]
```

I was trying to add above array for Codeigniter batch insert and it fails..
How to convert the above array for inserting to mysql database

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact, that you didn't show anything what you tried so far, you've to understand that your posted string isn't an Array - but a JSON String.

In order to achieve what you want you've to decode that string - based on the example below you should be able to understand how to do that

```
class Your_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function insert()
    {
        $strJson = '[{
            "synonyms": [{
                "synonyms": "s1",
                "wordId": 117
            }, {
                "synonyms": "s2",
                "wordId": 117
            }, {
                "synonyms": "s3",
                "wordId": 117
            }, {
                "synonyms": "s4",
                "wordId": 117
            }]
        }, {
            "synonyms": [{
                "synonyms": "s5",
                "wordId": 118
            }, {
                "synonyms": "s6",
                "wordId": 118
            }, {
                "synonyms": "s7",
                "wordId": 118
            }]
        }]';

        $arrData = json_decode($strJson);


        foreach($arrData AS $obj)
        {
            foreach($obj->synonyms AS $objSynonym)
            {
                $arrInsertData = [
                    "synonyms" => $objSynonym->synonyms,
                    "wordId" => $objSynonym->wordId
                ];

                $this->db->insert("your_table", $arrInsertData);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

as you can see an `insert_batch` isn't necessary because you've to iterate over your array anyway.